# When to layout subviews of UIViewControllers view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In my `UIViewController` class, I'm creating a `UIView` called `safeAreaView` and adding it as a subview to the `UIViewControllers` `view` property. I'm making it so `safeAreaView` takes up the entire safe area of the `UIViewControllers` `view` property:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [self setToolbarWithColor: self.mainToolbarColor animated:NO];

    self.tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    self.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    self.safeAreaView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    self.safeAreaView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.safeAreaView.delegate = self;
    self.safeAreaView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview: self.safeAreaView];

    [self.safeAreaView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.safeAreaView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.safeAreaView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor].active = YES;
    [self.safeAreaView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;

    [self.safeAreaView loadSubviews];
}
```

This works fine, but my problem is, at some point after this during the `UIViewControllers` initialization cycle, `safeAreaView` updates to account for the statusbar (it's y position moves up 20 and it decreases in size by 20).

I need to layout some subviews on `safeAreaView` and I don't know the proper time? If I attach the subviews like above, they have the wrong height. And I can't use some auto layout features on the subviews because there are specific things that I need to do. I've also tried executing the above code in `viewWillAppear` with no luck.

Wondering if anyone had any suggestions?

Comment: `[self.view addSubview: self.subView];` shouldn't you be adding the `safeAreaView`? And what does `loadSubviews` do?

Comment: @LukasWürzburger sorry that was a mistake, I've named that view subView in my code, but changed it to safeAreaView to avoid confusion when describing this question.

Comment: And what does `loadSubviews` do?

Comment: I guess you'll have to override `- (void)layoutSubviews` on your `safeAreaView` class and adjust the (non-autolayout) subviews manually (don't forget to call super)

Comment: Another option would be to override your `safeAreaView`'s class `frame` setter, so each time the frame of your view changes, you'll get a change to manually set any subview frames as needed.

Comment: @LukasWürzburger it lays out some subviews, but not in such a way that I can use auto-layout, I have to do some specific things there. Kept it in a blackbox to simplify the question.

Comment: @Alladinian thanks, layoutsubviews did the trick, that happened between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear. If you put this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @NSMoron Glad that helped. Posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `- (void)layoutSubviews` on your `safeAreaView` class:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Manual frame adjustment for non-autolayout participating subviews
    // ...
}
```

Another option would be to override your `safeAreaView`'s class frame setter, so each time the frame of your view changes, you'll get a chance to manually set any subview frames as needed.